# Passing variable name as argument in ## operator

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was learning the use of token parsing operator.
When I did as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define concat(a, b) a##b

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", concat(1, 2));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output : 12

But when I tried to pass arguments as variable name,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define concat(a, b) a##b

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = 3;
    printf("%d\n", concat(x, y));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Got error

```
'system' undefined; assuming extern returning int   
'xy': undeclared identifier
identifier "xy" is undefined
```

I read in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633026/c-macro-token-concatenation-involving-a-variable-is-it-possible) as "**C macros are really preprocessor macros that are expanded before compilation. The variable '*port*', doesn't get set until runtime."**

Okay, That's not possible. But when I tried this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define mult(a, b) a*b

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = 3;
    printf("%d\n", mult(x, y));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT : 6

Why this has no error, but with ## there's error

Comment: Because `mult(x, y)` is replaced by `x*y`, which is a legit expression.

Comment: If you use the `gcc` compiler, try running `gcc -E test.c >processed.c` to see what the `##` operator does. (Maybe remove the `#include <stdio.h>` header to reduce clutter.)

Comment: Think of the preprocessor as a separate program, which works on a text stream which may or may not be a C program. The preprocessor does not know C, it does not care about C language syntax or semantics. All it knows is to read text and do some substitutions. The C compiler proper sees only what comes out of the preprocessor. In you examples, the C compiler sees first `xy` and flags an undeclared variable, and then `x*y` which is an ordinary expression.

Comment: @AlexP `printf("%d\n", mult(x, y));` this line after preprocessing become `printf("%d\n", x*y);` or `printf("%d\n", 2*3);` Which is correct?

Comment: @Athul: *The preprocessor does not know C*. As far as the preprocessor is concerned the source text is just text. (You can actually run the C preprocessor or arbitrary text; sometimes this is quite useful.) *It does not understand that `int x = 2;` assigns the value 2 to the variable `x`.* So after preprocessing the line reads `printf ("%d\n", x*y);`.

Comment: The pre-processor replaces `mult(x, y)` by `x*y`, which then gets fed to the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

**Preprocessor doesn't know the C language.**

Preprocessor is **STUPID**. It does not run your program. It just takes the code and mechanically applies changes which you tell him to apply.  This changed code is compiled by C compilier.

when you write

```
#define concat(a,b) a##b
...
int x=2, y=3;
int z=concat(x,y);
```

It does NOT run the program to determine that x=2, y=3. For preprocessor, `int x=2, y=3;` is just a silly sequence of tokens whose meaning it doesn't understand.  It doesn't even know that `x` and `y` are variables.  It just knows that `concat` means concatenation of two tokens.  So it produces the code:

```
...
int x=2, y=3;
int z=xy;
```

Which then goes to the C compilier.

Comment: Not *knowing* something isn't necessarily "stupid" ... ;-)

Comment: @alk - it doesn't even *want* to know it. It is not curious :)